# Xpath URl и Анкор

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlhttprequest

Имею таблицу данных текст ссылки, саму ссылку и страницу сайта, где размещена эта ссылка.

Для примера (анкоры, ссылки все динамические):

> Анкор текста || site.ru || donor.ru

Вопрос как посредством Xpath проверить присутствие ссылки и анкора на страницах сайта donor.ru ? Причем должно быть 2 проверки на анкор и на ссылку ?

Парсинг буду производить через Гугл таблицы с помощью Importxml.

Comment: XPath для запросов xml/html, а не плоского текста.

Comment: Я через гугл таблицы хочу забирать информацию